# Remove active state when clicking another div

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

First of all, I am kind of new to React, so I am just getting into this Hooks stuff.
But basically I have a fixed menu with 5 buttons. When a button is clicked it will open some kind of overlay, different for all buttons.

For this I am currently using hooks, e.g:

```
const MobileNavigation = () => {

    const [menu1Toggle, setMenu1Toggle] = useState(false)
    const [menu2Toggle, setMenu2Toggle] = useState(false)
    const [menu3Toggle, setMenu3Toggle] = useState(false)
    const [menu4Toggle, setMenu4Toggle] = useState(false)
    const [menu5Toggle, setMenu5Toggle] = useState(false)
   
    return ( **below content**  )
}

export default memo(MobileNavigation)
```

And the div for each button looks like this:

```
<div className="menu-button" onClick={() => setMenu1Toggle(!menu1Toggle)}>
</div>
```

Which then activates this:

```
<div className={menu1Toggle ? 'menu1-container is-active' : 'menu1-container'}>
    <div className="content"></div>
</div>
```

So basically it appears because the `is-active` class is added when the button is clicked.

This approach kind of works, as in everything is working. However, all menus can be open at the same time with this approach. I would like it so that when one button is clicked only this button and its container is active, and it automatically disables the `is-active` class from whatever container is active.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrote this code.

```
export default function App() {
  const [menuToggles, setMenuToggles] = useState([
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false,
    false
  ]);

  const setMenuToggle = (index) => {
    let temp = [...menuToggles];
    for (let i = 0; i < menuToggles.length; i++) {
      if (index === i) temp[index] = !temp[index];
      else temp[i] = false;
    }
    setMenuToggles(temp);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {menuToggles.map((menu, index) => {
        return (
          <button className="menu-button" onClick={() => setMenuToggle(index)}>
            button{index + 1}
          </button>
        );
      })}

      <br />
      <hr />
      {menuToggles.map((menu, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            {menu
              ? `menu${index + 1}-container is-active`
              : `mobile-menu${index + 1}-container`}
            <br />
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Work Demo**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 0):

You can store the index of active menu.
current: stores the index of the last interacted button
active: will be true if one of the buttons is active

```
const MobileNavigation = () => {
   const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
   const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
   ...
}
```

In the place you render the buttons

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
return arr.map(menuIndex => (
<div className="menu-button" key={menuIndex} onClick={() => {setCurrent(menuIndex); setActive(current!==menuIndex)}}>
</div>
)
```

Render contents:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(index => 
<div className={((index === current) && active)? `menu{index}-container is-active` : 'mobile-menu-container'}>
    <div className="content"></div>
</div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you create toggle buttons array and map that to handle current position for making active/inactive.

If you are looking for something like this. you can change as per your requirement.

active class

```
<div className={oIndex === index ? "tile is-active" : "tile"}>
      <div className="left">
        <div>
          <div>{ar.head}</div>
          <div>
            {oIndex === index ? `Menu ${index}` : `Menu ${index}`}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.is-active {
  border: 2px solid darkcyan;
}
```

you can refer to [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-meadow-mw6jw) to understand how to make active the only one when clicked